# How to teach Eclipse some manners

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The spelling checker in my Eclipse has been naughty today by suggesting profanity (cfr. image).

[image]

How can I prevent it from being rude?

Comment: I agree not knowing idiom is odd so just add it to the dictionary. I don't see any profanity here

Comment: +1 Just because of the humor.  Eclipse has "idiot" which is one letter different than "idiom", so it suggests the closest word in its dictionary which was "idiot".

Comment: Now, confess, how many of you opened Eclipse to check?

Comment: You guys use the Eclipse dictionary for the comments? That's one of the first things I disable when installing Eclipse!

Answer (score 2):

**Just click on "Add 'idiom' to dictionary" option!!**

[image]

Anything else !?

Comment: But that won't stop Eclipse from being rude when given another chance later on!